# Wordpress: How to exclude users with default avatar from displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set default avatar in Wordpress settings if user didn't upload any of his own.

How to exclude users with default avatar from displaying?

Update: I'm using in php code get_avatars func and was wondering how to exclude users with no avatars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning the function to a variable then checking for it.

```
$avatar = get_avatar( $args );
if( $avatar ) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // If no avatar then do something else
}
```